# Is my approach accurate to find original position of boat?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A boat goes upstream for $3$ hr $30$ min and then goes downstream for $2$ hr $30$ min. If the speed of the current and the speed of the boat
in still water are $\frac{10}{3}$ kmph and $\frac{15}{2}$ kmph respectively, how far
from its original position is the boat now?

[image]

Speed of boat in still water$=\frac{15}{2}$

Speed of stream $=\frac{10}{3}$

Upstream speed $=\frac{15}{2}-\frac{10}{3}$

Downstream speed $=\frac{15}{2}+\frac{10}{3}$

→ Downstream distance - Upstream distance = far from original.

$=\left(2+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{15}{2}+\frac{10}{3}\right) - \left(3+\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(\frac{15}{2}-\frac{10}{3}\right)$

$=\left(\frac{5}{2}\right)\left(\frac{65}{6}\right) - \left(\frac{7}{2}\right)\left(\frac{25}{6}\right)$

$=\frac{325-175}{12}$

→ **$12.5$ km downstream**.

Is my approach accurate to find original position of boat?

Comment: Please remove the gap between ":" and "/" to view the image.

Comment: I got the same answer, $12.5~\text{km}$. However, I think it would be wiser to set up a coordinate system. It runs so that the downstream distance is positive. In this case, the upstream speed is actually $\frac{10}{3} - \frac{15}{2}$. The answer remains the same, but some of the signs are flipped in this approach. The expression that I have is
$$
\left( \frac{10}{3}- \frac{15}{2} \right) \frac{7}{2} + 
\left( \frac{10}{3}+\frac{15}{2} \right) \frac{5}{2} = 12.5
$$

Answer (score 1):

Your method looks great. As an alternative:

With reference to ground, the water travels downstream for $2.5+3.5=6$ hours.
With reference to water, the boat went upstream for $1$ hour. So the boat is 
$$ \frac{10}{3} \times 6- \frac{15}{2}\times 1 = 12.5$$
$km$ downstream from the start.

Comment: How boat went upstream for **1 hour only** if question clearly says boat goes upstream for **3 hr 30 min**?

Comment: What happens if you go north for $3.5$ hours, and then south for $2.5$ hours ?

Comment: Explain me why subtracting $\frac{15}{2}\times 1$ from total distance i.e $\frac{10}{3} \times 6$?

Comment: Alright! Imagine you fell into the water and drowning along the stream. Where would you be in $6$ hours?

Comment: I would be at **6 x whatever stream speed is.**

Comment: The speed of the stream is given as 10/3kmph

Comment: So Why subtracting $\frac{15}{2}\times 1$?

Comment: Next further imagine that while drowning along the stream, you were watching the boat.

Comment: Since both you and the boat are on water, in relation to you the boat has travelled for 3.5 hours away from you and then 2.5 hours towards you

Comment: Can you figure out how far the boat is away from you after 6 hours?